# WebView in MasterView Controller

Tags: ipad, uiwebview

I would like to display a webview useful to unlock a website providing data for the detail view controller in the master controller of the iPad version. Yet when I do so, similarly to what I successfully do with a TableView, just the ViewDidLoad callback gets called, but not the ViewWillAppear and in general it seems nothing happens like the view were not shown. My code seamlessly works in the iPhone version, while I checked the StoryBoard several times without finding anything suspect. Any idea about what is the reason for that and a solution?

Answer (score 0):

At any rate I substituted the MasterController with a PopUp and everything works finely: still doubtful why a WebView cannot be shown in the masterViewController: perhaps just tableviews may show there.